# how to change default browser on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iOS and I want to know that, How to change the default browser as Google chrome on iPhone Simulator?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why ?? pls give a reason ... http://www.informationweek.com/development/mobility/chrome-for-ios-as-your-default-browser/240003564

Comment: not possible on simulator because you can't install chrome in simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As xlc has mentioned the Simulator doesn't allow you to install third party applications. It's designed to let you test your code and how it interacts with iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change default iOS default browser unless and until your device is jailbroken.

but you can open links in google chrome from your app using :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"googlechrome://http://www.nameofwebsitehere.com"]];
```

Note : this will not work on simulator and you should add a check to see if Google chrome is installed on device.